# 20.04 desktop intel UHD 630 video problems

Tags: multiple-monitors, 20.04, intel-graphics, ubuntu-drivers

I install fresh 20.04 desktop as second OS.
It freeze on boot process. I added 'nomodeset' for startup line and get to login screen. Now I trying get correct video drivers OR solve 1) permanent boot solution (wihout "nomodset"); 2) work on two monitors.

My devices are:

```
ubuntu:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
V5.0.0.13 R1.6.0 for D3643-H1x

ubuntu:~$ sudo cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep 'name'| uniq
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9400 CPU @ 2.90GHz

ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
```

And two monitors: Dell SE2416H (standard FullHD). For now work only on one and Ubuntu can't recognize it. Maybe it's because DisplayPort -> converter -> HDMI cable-> DellMonitor

Comment: How to install correct video drivers for Intel UHD Graphics 630 on 20.04?

Comment: For now I got solution to boot normally ubuntu 20.04 by pressing F1 at the OS starting process. I don't know what this F1 do, but after successfully OS loading, OS recognize my multiple monitors.